# layout issue in iPad when running the iPhone app in iPad (Objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have an issue with the iPhone app. I have implemented one **iPhone app (not universal)**. When I am creating the new project I have **deleted the Launch Screen,Story board from the project and implemented the MainWindow.xib** like in the old format. I have **designed the xibs for iPhone 5**. So in iPhone 5,6 and 6 plus everything is working fine. But When I run the iPhone app in the iPad the bottom part got cut off. If I **design the xibs for iPhone 4**, eventhough I added the Default-568h@2x.png it is not supporting for iPhone 5 but working well in iPad.For reference I have attached the screenshot . The screenshot for iPhone 5 screen. It is not scaling to iPhone 5 after adding the Default-568h@2x.png. Black color part width is 568-480=88 pixels.

[image]

So please guide me to handle the iPhone 4,5,6,6 plus and iPad.Thank you for spending the valuable time. Please let me know if I am not clear.

I am using xcode 8.0 and iOS 10.0

Comment: add lunch image for every screen

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Please explain me indetail

Comment: add one new lunchImage in Assets.xcasssets and add all require images as per resolution.

Comment: When I am adding the Default-568h@2x.png why I have to add new launch image?